# "You have a final exam next session." or "You have final exam next session."?

Tags: grammar, articles

This may sound like too basic a question but it's been bugging me for a while now. Which of the following is correct/preferable: "You have a final exam next session." "You have final exam next session." "You have the final exam next session." 
And I'm not talking about school exams. Otherwise I would just say "finals". It's a language institute and there is only one subject--English. So I don't think "You have finals" would be the best option.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You have the final exam next session" is best.

"You have a final exam next session" would only make sense if there were more than one final exam.

"You have final exam next session" is syntactically incorrect.

Source: native English speaker

Comment: Thank you so much. 

And one more related question please, is "Yesterday was off but today we have class." correct? (It doesn't matter how many classes we have, there may be one or more)

Comment: "We had yesterday off but today we have class" or "Yesterday was a day off but today we have class"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I'm having difficulty understanding why "We have exam tomorrow (no article)." is syntactically incorrect while "We have class tomorrow (again, no article)." is  correct.

Comment: It is a different type of noun. This is where I would need some help from a professional linguist

Comment: Thankssss for your help.